# If NL = P, prove that P!=PSPACE

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

If NL = P, how do we prove that P != PSPACE?
Do we have to use Savitch's theorem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

By Savitch's theorem, $NL \subseteq DSPACE(\log^2 n)$, and, by a diagonalization argument, $DSPACE(\log^2 n) \subsetneq PSPACE$.  So, $NL\subsetneq PSPACE$, and, if $NL=P$, $P\subsetneq PSPACE$.